# json service casting error

Tags: c#, winforms, json.net

i have following code  latitude,latitude its show 0 how get values please help.

http://private-anon-397aeee05-karhoofleetintegration.apiary-mock.com/trip?version=2&karhoo_ref=karhoo_ref

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var json = client.DownloadString("http://private-anon-397aeee05-karhoofleetintegration.apiary-mock.com/trip?version=2&karhoo_ref=karhoo_ref.asmx");
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
             BookingInformation bo = serializer.Deserialize<BookingInformation>(json.ToString());

        }
    }


public class BookingInformation
{
      public string karhoo_ref { get; set; }
public string booking_id { get; set; }


public string datetime_scheduled_utc { get; set; }
public string status { get; set; }
public bool is_asap { get; set; }

public decimal latitude { get; set; }

public decimal longitude { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: asp.net i have code but c# don't no how do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deserialize that JSON you need to provide objects that reflects the JSON itself, what you have above is nothing even close to complete. A quick JSON > C# class conversion gives this:

```
public class Address
{
public string display_address { get; set; }
public string building_number { get; set; }
public string street_name { get; set; }
public string city { get; set; }
public string region { get; set; }
public string postal_code { get; set; }
public string country { get; set; }
}

public class Airport
{
public string airport_code { get; set; }
public string airline_code { get; set; }
public string terminal { get; set; }
public string flight_number { get; set; }
public int meet_greet { get; set; }
}

public class FromLocation
{
public double latitude { get; set; }
public double longitude { get; set; }
public Address address { get; set; }
public string comment { get; set; }
public Airport airport { get; set; }
}

public class Address2
{
public string display_address { get; set; }
public string building_number { get; set; }
public string street_name { get; set; }
public string city { get; set; }
public string region { get; set; }
public string postal_code { get; set; }
public string country { get; set; }
}

public class ToLocation
{
public double latitude { get; set; }
public double longitude { get; set; }
public Address2 address { get; set; }
public object comment { get; set; }
public object airport { get; set; }
}

public class Passenger
{
public string first_name { get; set; }
public string last_name { get; set; }
public string phone_number { get; set; }
public bool is_primary_contact { get; set; }
}

public class Direction
{
public int kph { get; set; }
public int heading { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
public string vehicle_type { get; set; }
public string vehicle_id { get; set; }
public string vehicle_plate { get; set; }
public double latitude { get; set; }
public double longitude { get; set; }
public object eta_minutes { get; set; }
public string make { get; set; }
public string model { get; set; }
public string color { get; set; }
public string status { get; set; }
public string driver_id { get; set; }
public string driver_phone { get; set; }
public string driver_first_name { get; set; }
public string driver_last_name { get; set; }
public Direction direction { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
public string karhoo_ref { get; set; }
public string booking_id { get; set; }
public int datetime_scheduled_utc { get; set; }
public string status { get; set; }
public bool is_asap { get; set; }
public bool as_directed { get; set; }
public FromLocation from_location { get; set; }
public ToLocation to_location { get; set; }
public string notes { get; set; }
public int passenger_count { get; set; }
public int luggage_count { get; set; }
public List<Passenger> passengers { get; set; }
public Vehicle vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

So, try and deserialize the data into those class objects. It should at least give you the data.

Comment: thanks your great boss :)

Comment: its very helpful for me :)